# How can I reverse string to bin?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

How can I convert bin to string?
For example:

```
 string:='s';----------->bin:='0011';
```

How do I convert it reverse?

My stringtobin code is:

```
function StrToBinStr( aString: string ): string;
var
i : integer;
begin
for i := 1 to Length( aString ) do
result := IntToBin( byte(aString[i]), 4 );
end;

function IntToBin(aValue, Bits: integer): string;
var
i : integer;
begin
for i := Bits-1 downto 0 do
result := result + Copy( '10', Word(((1 shl i) and AValue) = 0)+1, 1 );
end;
```

Comment: Why would you convert an Ansi string to binary and then back? It makes sense to convert 'A' to hex $41, and that's an easy conversion back and forth: `sTemp := IntToHex(Ord('A'), 2); iTemp := StrToInt('$' + sTemp);`. The problem with binary is that it's easy to convert `A` to `1000001`, converting it back is harder - there's no predictable number of characters, unless you always use  the max width of an AnsiChar (255, $FF or 11111111, which is 8 digits - note the `A` representation above is only 7). Using hex instead, you can always use two digits ($01 - $FF) to represent any AnsiChar.

Comment: Also, how is 's' = '0011' in any sense? Even if you're using straight alpha-numeric substitution (eg., 'a' = 1, 'b' = 2, 'c' = 3), 's' = 19 = '10011'.

Comment: I'm not surprised you need so much compression if you really are converting strings to textual representations of their hex character codes.

Comment: @Cenk, I guess you're using STRINGS to encode your Huffman bit values. That's a very bad, and highly inefficient idea. If you can't figure out a way to do proper bit manipulation give up now, revisit the idea in a few years when you'll be more comfortable using `AND`, `OR`, `SHL` and bit masks.

Comment: @Cenk You've asked a lot of questions now and you appear to be going round in circles. You clearly have a very poor understanding of how computers work.  You really need to step back, go back to basics and get a better grounding in computing.  You also need to learn to ask the right questions.  You should be asking help with your real problem, not help with your haphazard efforts to solve the problem. We can't really you properly until you tell us what your real problem is.  Go right back to the beginning and tell us all about it.

Answer (score 3):

This may help:

```
function  IntToBin( const Value: LongInt; Digits: Byte;
  const Spaces: Boolean ): AnsiString;
begin
  if Digits > 32 then
    Digits := 32;
  SetLength( Result, Digits );
  Result := '';
  while Digits > 0 do
  begin
    if (Spaces) and ((Digits mod 8) = 0) then
      Result := Result + #32;
    Dec(Digits, 1);
    Result := Result + IntToStr((Value shr Digits) and 1);
  end;
end;

function BinToInt( Value: AnsiString ): LongInt;
var
  cTmp: AnsiChar;
  liCtr, liLen: LongInt;
begin
  Value := AnsiString(StringReplace(Value, #32, '', [rfReplaceAll]));
  liLen := Length(Value);
  cTmp := Value[liLen];
  Dec(liLen);
  Result := StrToInt(cTmp);
  liCtr := 1;
  while liLen > 0 do
  begin
    cTmp := Value[liLen];
    Dec( liLen );
    Result := Result + (StrToInt(cTmp) shl liCtr );
    Inc(liCtr);
  end;
end;
```

Sample use:

```
procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
var
  TestStr: AnsiString;
  i: Integer;
  Temp: AnsiString;
begin
  TestStr := 'ABC';
  Temp := '';
  for i := 1 to Length(TestStr) do
    Temp := Temp + IntToBin(Ord(AnsiChar(TestStr[i])), 8, False);
  ShowMessage('Temp = ' + Temp);

  TestStr := '';
  i := 1;
  while i < Length(Temp) do
  begin
    TestStr := TestStr + AnsiChar(BinToInt(Copy(Temp, i, 8)));
    Inc(i, 8);
  end;
  ShowMessage('TestStr = ' + TestStr);
end;
```

As I said in my comment to your original question, I think this is a terrible idea, but these work.

Comment: But I get 8 bit in your code,but I want to get 4 bytes look at my example code..For example I want to get 2-->0011 not 00000011.

Comment: @Cenk, the decimal number `2` converts to the binary number `10`, not `11`; Only numbers `< 16` can be converted to 4 bits: How do you convert, for example, decimal number `17` to only 4 bits binary?

Comment: Ok,I couldnt understand,,Could you tell me what is binary code of "♀5Å╣òshello" ? Is my code wrong?

Comment: And because I have 10000000000 character string.If I use this code it will be 8*1000000000..it is too big..

Comment: @Cenk: What is that? That looks like something you pulled out of a compiled binary.

Comment: @Cenk: If that would be too big, then try converting to hex instead.  Whether or not it would be too big is irrelevant; Cosmin's point is that it's not possible to convert binary bytes to a representation in bits without either using 8 bits per byte or losing some information that makes it impossible to convert back.  And if you're using high characters like `♀Å╣ò`, you're definitely going to need all 8 of those bits.

Comment: @Cenk, you're on the *wrong* path: You shouldn't convert file data to string to begin with, treat it as plain and simple bytes. You shouldn't load the whole data at once, so there's no 8*1000000000, there's only 8*SmallBufferSize; You shouldn't work with bit data as CHAR/STRING, it is wasteful and inefficient. You need to understand what binary, decimal and hexadecimal notation is. You need to really understand why 4 bits are not enough if you need to store 17 different values of anything.

Comment: @Cosmin: That was the question I asked in my comments. Converting 's' to '0011' is nonsense, and converting even 'A' requires more than 4 bits. I provided the code to convert an int to a binary representation and back, and showed how to convert a string to the binary representation of it's characters. I don't understand what the OP is really trying to do either, though - I suspect it's related to the other questions posted by the same person related to compression.

Answer (score 0):

```
function _ConvertHexToWideString(AHex: AnsiString): WideString;
var wBinaryStream: TMemoryStream;
begin
  try
    wBinaryStream := TMemoryStream.Create;

    try
      wBinaryStream.Size := Length(AHex) div 2;

      if wBinaryStream.Size > 0 then
        HexToBin(PAnsiChar(AHex), wBinaryStream.Memory, wBinaryStream.Size);
    except
    end;

    SetString(Result, PWideChar(wBinaryStream.Memory), wBinaryStream.Size div SizeOf(WideChar));
  finally
    FreeAndNil(wBinaryStream);
  end;
end;
```